# How to upload pdf file into my own server?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, file-upload

In my site, user want to  upload a pdf file and I have to save it into my own server. I don't need the content to be saved. I want the exact file to be copied into my server where the published file of the site exists.How to do this?

Comment: Is it my weak comprehension? So how I got confused by wha seems to be a straightforward question.

Comment: I just want to upload the pdf file. I don't need my the content of the file to be saved. I need the exact file to be copied into my system. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use asp.net fileupload control: [Uploading files in asp.net using C#](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/network/net-fileupload-aspnet2-csharp.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use FileUpload Control and write code like

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs("Path and Filename");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.NET file upload control which will handle this.You can mention where in your server you want to store it